# What does this |_ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In this code:

```
arr.select.each_with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
```

what does pipe underscore mean?

Comment: It's the `|` followed by a _variable_ named `_` (which ruby allows)

Comment: In ruby, you could name a variable `` if you wish.

Comment: The `|..|` declares *block parameters* - search for "ruby block parameter". `_` is a valid variable name which, as convention, is somteimes used to represent 'this parameter is not used meaningfully'.

Comment: gosh, I am so silly! thanks!

Answer (score 10):

`_` is a variable name like every other variable name (for example `i`).

It is a convention in Ruby to use `_` as a variable name or prefix variable names with `_` (like `_i`) as an indication that you do not plan to use that variable later on.

In your example, `each_with_index` yields two values in each step of the iteration: The current element and the current index.

```
each_with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
```

The author of the code needed to name both values but decided to indicate with the variable name `_` that they do not care about the current value, only about the current index.

Comment: Thanks :) appreciate it!

Comment: this also applies to other languages!  some languages use that as a standard convention, like Golang and Rust lang

Comment: The use of `_` (actually any variable the begins with `_`) is more than a convention, there's code in MRI specifically to suppress certain warnings when using such variables.

Comment: Further to @muistooshort's comment (and not just suppression of warnings): `[[1,2,3]].map { |a,a,c| c } #=>SyntaxError: duplicated argument name` vs `[[1,2,3]].map { |_,_,c| c } #=> [3]` (Ruby 2.3). I expect this example reflects the main difference between local variables named `_` and other local variables.

Answer (score 2):

In a function, the arguments are enclosed in parenthesis:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2)
    ..
end
```

In a block, you use the pipes to enclose the arguments:

```
arr.each_with_index{ |item, index| .. }
```

In this case, the variable name choosen as the first argument for the block, was `_`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method `each_with_index` and passing it an anonymous function (or "block"). That block takes two parameters: the first represents an item in the array (or enumerable object) and the second represents its index (0 for the first element, 1 for the second, 2 for the third, and so on).

Assigning the name `_` in Ruby (and some other languages) is the conventional way of saying "I'm not going to use this." So `each_with_index { |_, i| ... }` means "In this block, `i` represents the index, and I don't care about the element itself so I'm not giving it a name."

Comment: Calling a block an _anonymous function_ is potentially very misleading. Just call it a block, and maybe provide some reference of what that is in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed advice!

Comment: It's more than a convention. Using the same parameter name multiple times is an error (e.g. `def foo(bar, bar) end` or `[].each {|foo, foo|}` will both raise an error) but not when the parameter is named `_` or starts with `_` (`def foo(_bar, _bar) end` and `[].each {|_foo, _foo|}` are both fine). Also, Ruby will warn about unused local variables, but not when the variable name starts with `_` or is `_`.